# Passing **args to super()

Tags: python, inheritance, arguments

In the base class have a constructor which takes multiple arguments.

```py
class Base:
    def __init__(self,*args):
        self.items = list(args)
    def add(self,*items):
        for i in items:
            self.items.append(i)

class Inherited(Base):
    def __init__(self,*args):
        super().__init__(args)
        self.items.sort()
    def add(self,*args):
        super().add(args)
        self.items.sort()

c = Inherited('b','c','a')
c.add('f','e','d')
print(c.items)
```

It works well enough if I use the base class, but I have problems when I use the inherited class.

When I use the inherited class, I find that the arguments have been sent as a single tuple. That’s not what I meant.

How can I pass the `*args` as multiple arguments to the `super()` constructor?

Comment: `super().__init__(*args)`?

Comment: @Brian Damn, you’re right. I though I had tried that. If you put that int an answer, i can accept it. Thanks